# How assemble a Maven projects with "very large" file dependencies

Tags: maven

I've got a project that assembles a server build. Some of the components are very large, one or two over 500MB, totalling about 4GB. I'd like to assemble them into a single artefact (well, a directory) as part of the package phase.

Our artifatory has a 200MB limit, so they cannot go in there, they need to live on a file share. I'd like the benefits of artefacts (local cache, versioning). A clean install would copy the files to the target directory, taking about an one to hours to complete and putting a heavy load an the network.

Any thoughts how I do this?

Comment: Can't you increase that limit?

Comment: 10 seconds of googling finds https://issues.jfrog.org/jira/browse/RTFACT-227  (it is a bad idea to go againt the grain of the maven system, best to resolve the limit issue; good luck on your quest if you intend to do roll your own solution :P )

Comment: No. The artifactory simply doesn't have large enough disks for many large artifacts. I should have said.

Comment: If your artifactory has not a enough disk space you are doing things wrong, cause the idea of a repository manager is to store all artifacts. The result in a company is that a repository become larger and larger over the time. And usually i wouldn't be astonished having repositories over 100-200 GB...(to limit the upload limit sounds wrong. Cause nobody knows how large an artifact can become? And that can break builds!).

Comment: The questions is: Do you need the whole size for every build or are there many parts of that which a usually the same which do not change (images, videos etc.) Just put the into a different project (artifact and just use the dependency).